# Pycharm Run not recognizing latex commands

Tags: python, console, latex, interpreter

If I like to run my code in pycharm via run command in a IPython console, the run does not recognize \unitfrac{}{}.
But if I run the code manually at Python Console it works without problems:

### IPython Console (RUN):

PyDev console: using IPython 6.2.1

Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

- Unknown symbol: \unitfrac (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)

BUT:

### Python Console (Manually):

Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information

IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

PyDev console: using IPython 6.2.1

Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
from matplotlib import verbose

rc('font', family='sans-serif', size=7)
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('text.latex', preamble=r"\usepackage{units},\usepackage{cmbright}")
verbose.level = 'debug-annoying'
rc('ps', usedistiller='xpdf')
rc('pdf', fonttype=42)
rc('ps', fonttype=42)

plt.plot(range(10), label="$\\unitfrac{2}{3}$")
plt.legend()
```

works fine.

Comment: I think it has something to do with loading Python 3.6.4 on win 32 before the run. This is not happening as it does on the python console.

Comment: And yes, when I start the code after the failure again by manually copiing it in to the run console, it plots the figure without problems. How can I make pycharm to load the PYthon 3.6.4 on win 32 before the run?